# How to display values of a bound datagrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF application and I'm usign the MVVM design approach.

I have an ObservableObject which holds a list of the class Transaction which is below;

```
public Transaction
{
    public string Ammount;
    public string Direction;
}
```

The ObservableObject in my ViewModel is below

```
public ObservableCollection<Transactions> ListOfUserTransactions
        {
            get { return _localTransactionData; }
            set
            {
                _localTransactionData = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ListOfUserTransactions");
            }
        }
```

And my view binds in this way;

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfUserTransactions}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ammount" Binding="{Binding Path=Ammount}"  Foreground="Black" IsReadOnly="True" />

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Direction" Binding="{Binding Path=Direction}" Foreground="Black" IsReadOnly="True" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This does work in a way as the number of rows produced equal what i was expecting but all the rows are empty, i presume it is the way i am binding the DataGridTextColumn but im unsure as how to do it, hope there is enough detail in the above question.

**EDIT**

below is how the transaction list is created

```
ObservableCollection<Transaction> _localTransactionData = new ObservableCollection<Transaction>();


        public TransactionsViewModel(User passedThroughUser)
        {
            _user = passedThroughUser;
            _listOfTransactions = _user.Transactions;

            foreach (var item in _listOfTransactions)
            {
                LocalTransactionsList tran = new LocalTransactionsList();
                tran.Ammount = item.Ammount.ToString(); ;
                tran.Direction = item.Direction;
                _localTransactionData.Add(tran);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have done so with no luck, still blank fields

Comment: could you show the full implementation of Transaction , 
i wan't you to debug the getter of these properties , so add a private value for each one and return and set it .

Comment: Did you consider having your text columns binding to properties instead of fields?

Comment: no sorry, how would i do this?

Comment: I'll include this as an answer below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
public Transaction
{
    public string Ammount;
    public string Direction;
}
```

should be:

```
public Transaction
{
    public string Ammount {get;set;}
    public string Direction {get;set;}
}
```

Binding properties must have the setter and getter.

Comment: ahhhh its been winding me up for hours and its as simple as that, i kept looking over that class thinking 'it cant be that' and moving on, thanks so much for that

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. Anyway the @Garry Vass is also a very good answer...his solution allows you to show modifications on UI when the "datasource" is changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the behaviour you are after by changing your Transaction class to this...

```
public class Transaction : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _amount;
    public string Amount
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _amount; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _amount)
            {
                _amount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Amount");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _direction;
    public string Direction
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _direction; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _direction)
            {
                _direction = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Direction");
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

This will enable the WPF binding engine to access your properties and bind them correctly.

More about INPC here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx